# How to use Logger inside a Resque's worker in a pure ruby application

Tags: ruby, logging, resque

I have a ruby application (**not Rails**) using Resque. I'd like to know what's going on in one of the worker I have.

To do that, I use the Logger class as stated [in the officiel documentation](https://github.com/resque/resque/wiki/Logging).

Below is how I log inside a worker:

```
require 'resque'
require 'logger'

<code>

Resque.logger = Logger.new File.new('logfile.log', 'a')
Resque.logger.info "Whatever"
```

However, when running my worker, **nothing is actually being logged**. It's as if the worker is actually ignoring all those log instructions. No error is raised. The other pieces of code actually work - only the logging part is ignored.

I tried to use the logger class itself (ie `logger = Logger.new`) but the result is the same.

**Do you have any idea on how I can actually log something inside my resque worker?**

Thanks!

Comment: Did you have any luck here?

Comment: Could it be that the logger is not autoflushing and therefore not writing? http://ruckus.tumblr.com/post/11619655587/logging-to-railslogger-from-a-resque-job

Answer (score 1):

Use the following:

```
Logger.new(path_to_log_file).info(anything)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the log level to enabled printing info logs, according to the documentation you linked there, you can use something like this

```
Resque.logger.level = Logger::DEBUG
```

then if you look into [Logger docs](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/logger/rdoc/Logger.html#class-Logger-label-Setting+severity+threshold) it lists levels as

> DEBUG < INFO < WARN < ERROR < FATAL < UNKNOWN

so if you are using `logger.info` you either need `Logger::DEBUG` or `Logger::INFO` to have the logged string to show up.

Also make sure the logger initialization is run by the process running the workers, and not just the process enqueueing jobs.

Comment: For the last couple of days, I tried almost all techniques I could find on internet, including yours. Simply nothing happens. I don't have any errors with what you wrote, however nothing is being logged at all. I really don't get it.

Comment: @henritroyat then you probably need `VERBOSE=1` set on your env

Answer (score 0):

my environment: rails 5.0.1, resque: 1.26.0.

I tried config the resque logger in `config/initializers/resque.rb` and `lib/tasks/resuqe.rake`, they neither work for me.

but config the resque logger inside every job, that works for me, although it is not perfect.

```
# update_xxx_job.rb
class UpdateXxxJob
  def self.perform
    Resque.logger = Logger.new("#{Rails.root}/log/resque.log")
    Resque.logger.level = Logger::DEBUG   

    Resque.logger.info 'Job starts'
    ...
  end
end
```

more details in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46787779/2998877).