# View Resque log output in Rails server logs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, logging, resque, resque-scheduler

I've got a Rails 4 app on a Puma server with Resque/Resque-Scheduler running background jobs. What I'd like to know is how I merge the log output of my two Resque workers into my server log, or, of that is not possible, how I can view the log output of my Resque workers. Currently I have not been able to figure out how to view the log output for the workers, so I have no idea what's happening under the hood. I found [this blogpost](http://jademind.com/blog/posts/enable-immediate-log-messages-of-resque-workers/), which suggests adding the following likes to my `resque.rake` file:

```
task "resque:setup" => :environment do
  Resque.before_fork = Proc.new { 
    ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection

    # Open the new separate log file
    logfile = File.open(File.join(Rails.root, 'log', 'resque.log'), 'a')

    # Activate file synchronization
    logfile.sync = true

    # Create a new buffered logger
    Resque.logger = ActiveSupport::BufferedLogger.new(logfile)
    Resque.logger.level = Logger::INFO
    Resque.logger.info "Resque Logger Initialized!"
  }
end
```

That didn't work. I also tried the suggestion in the comments, which was to replace `Resque.logger = ActiveSupport::BufferedLogger.new(logfile)` with `Resque.logger = ActiveSupport::Logger.new(logfile)`, however that didn't work either. With the second option, I still get a `NoMethodError: undefined method 'logger=' for Resque:Module` error when I try to boot up a worker.

Here is my current `resque.rake` file:

```
require 'resque/tasks'
require 'resque_scheduler/tasks'

namespace :resque do
    puts "Loading Rails environment for Resque"
    task :setup => :environment do
        require 'resque'
        require 'resque_scheduler'
        require 'resque/scheduler'
        require 'postman'
    end
end
```

I've looked at the [Resque docs on logging](https://github.com/resque/resque/wiki/Logging), but am not sure how to use what's there as I admittedly don't know very much about logging in Rails. I haven't had any luck finding other useful resources on the subject.

Comment: Did you ever get this solved?

Comment: Sort of. I noticed awhile back that the logs from Resque and Resque Scheduler were being outputted to my main server log on Heroku, but I never figured out (mainly because I don't have the time to put into it right now) what triggered the change in behavior. I suspect it may because I increased my Rails logging output from `info` to `debug` and/or because I upgraded from Rails 4.0.2 to 4.2.5. This only changed the log output on Heroku, but that's the reason I asked the question initially to begin with.. On localhost I still need to view the logs for each process individually.

Answer (score 5):

How I fix it, it is not perfect but just works.

my environment: rails 5.0.1, resque: 1.26.0

at the first time, I set the `Resque.logger` and `Resque.logger.level` in `config/initializers/resque.rb` as most docs suggest:

```
# config/initializers/resque.rb
Resque.logger = Logger.new("#{Rails.root}/log/resque.log")
Resque.logger.level = Logger::DEBUG
```

then in the job, I output log by `Resque.logger.info`:

```
# update_xxx_job.rb
class UpdateXxxJob
  def self.perform
    Resque.logger.info 'Job starts'
    ...
  end
end
```

it doesn't work, I can see nothing in `log/resque.log`.

then someone said should set the logfile sync always, no buffer, so I update the `config/initializers/resque.rb` according [a question from stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30776842/where-should-i-define-my-resque-logger-in-my-rails-application):

```
# config/initializers/resque.rb
logfile = File.open(File.join(Rails.root, 'log', 'resque.log'), 'a')
logfile.sync = true
Resque.logger = ActiveSupport::Logger.new(logfile)
Resque.logger.level = Logger::INFO
```

still doesn't work.

I also tried config resque logger in `lib/tasks/resque.rake`:

```
# lib/tasks/resque.rake
require 'resque'
require 'resque/tasks'
require 'resque/scheduler/tasks'
require 'resque-scheduler'
require 'resque/scheduler/server'

namespace :resque do
  task setup: :environment do
    Resque.schedule = YAML.load_file(Rails.root + "config/resque_scheduler_#{Rails.env}.yml")

    Resque.redis.namespace = "xxx_#{Rails.env}"

    Resque.logger = Logger.new("#{Rails.root}/log/resque.log")
    Resque.logger.level = Logger::INFO
  end
end
```

doesn't work.

finally, I decide to move the logger configuration from initializer to the job, so the job now looks like:

```
# update_xxx_job.rb
class UpdateXxxJob
  def self.perform
    Resque.logger = Logger.new("#{Rails.root}/log/resque.log")
    Resque.logger.level = Logger::DEBUG   

    Resque.logger.info 'Job starts'
    ...
  end
end
```

then I can get what I want in the `log/resque.log`.

you can try it.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue so that I check the source of `resque` and finally I needed to do the followings at initialization process:

1. define log formatter.
2. then define logger with log-file path.
3. set any log level.

Here the example is at my config/initializers/resque.rb in rails case:

```
...
Resque.logger           = Logger.new("#{Rails.root}/log/resque.log")
Resque.logger.level     = Logger::DEBUG
Resque.logger.formatter = ::Logger::Formatter.new   # This is important
```

Resque default logger formatter is set [here](https://github.com/resque/resque/blob/daf45bbbaf87411d27c0eb1df44ce463746cf5c8/lib/resque.rb#L651) and its definitions is [here](https://github.com/resque/resque/blob/v2.4.0/lib/resque/log_formatters/quiet_formatter.rb). That apparently just ignores the output...

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem while setting up mine. Here's what I did:

```
Resque.before_fork do
  # Your code here
end
```

It seems `before_fork` accepts a block as an argument rather than assigning a block to it.